# How to recreate Report Builder from example with groups

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I would like to obtain this grouping in Rep Builder (see the first grouping in the below picture). At the moment I have no groups created. How do I create these groups? There are many options: Add group - parent/child/adjacent below/above and maybe other options that I'm unaware of. etc.
The main thing that interests me if avoiding merged cells in groups (e.g. if I have 2 rows with the same value for company, I need the 2 rows to be UNMerged). Thank you.

Can you show me please how you obtained the first grouping (I obtain the second):
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please add an example of the tablix you want to get. At first glance I think you want to group by DC,Company (I don't know what backoffice means in your context):

With this dataset

[image]

**EDIT: Based on your comments**

Set row groups as follows:
[image]

**Note** the dotted line between DC and Company columns it indicates the grouped columns and the not grouped columns. If you want to group by company but don't group by DC you should add only that column to the row groups as parent. It will put the company as first column delete if you have added it to the tablix already.

And you'll get this preview:

[image]

**Note** DC is not grouped as you mention as requeriment in comments.

As mentioned previously I don't know if `Backoffice` is a column you can aggregate. So I am just guessing data for example purpose.
Let me know if this is what you need.

Comment: It looks like this exactly what I need. Can you describe please how you added the row groups in this manner? Usually, when I create a new group, a new column is added in the tablix; however, I see that in your example, this doesn't occur. It would help me to know how you added the group, what buttons you pressed etc. I generally like to add them from the window "Row Group", it's easier.

Comment: By the way, very important - another thing is I need the cells to be unmerged: B should appear twice in your example. Thank you!

Comment: Only keep in the tablix the grouped columns you need otherwise delete it. When you add a row group a new column is added to the tablix keep that one. Check my answer I have edited it.

Comment: Alejandro, how did you obtain the "≡" next to the second group in "Row groups"? I can only obtain it with a "[". See the picture in the edited question please.

Comment: Add a new tablix (if you use a modified tablix maybe it won't work), expand your dataset and drag company to row groups above "≡(details)" then drag the DC field from dataset and drop it to the tablix on the right side of company column then do the same for Backoffice dropping it to the right of DC column.

Comment: Gracias! Unfortunately, I added a new tablix but by default after creating it, it has all the fields nested one inside the other in "Row groups", each with a "[" sign, no "≡" sign at all (we are probably creating the tablix differently:  I use the wizard and add all text fields in the ROW section and all value fields in the Value section). How can I convert a group with "[" into one with "≡"?

Comment: I also don't know why after creating the tablix with a wizard, the groups don't duplicate columns, but if I add a new group manually, it also duplicates the columns. How can I add a new group (logically) without creating a column simultaneously?

Comment: Oh if you are using wizard it will place dataset fields in tablix. My solution works if you create a empty report and add a tablix. For further conversation comments are not proper, it would be better to create another question with a specific question or lets use a chatroom

Comment: Alejandro, thanks a million for your help. I never had that dotted line when I used the wizard. Your answers have helped me tremendously. Thank you for your insistence to clarify this.